# Find the first four nonzero terms in the Maclaurin of $e^x \sin x$

Tags: real-analysis

> > Given the following theorem $f$ and $g$ 
> >     $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-x_0)^n, |x-x_0| < R_1 \\ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n (x-x_0)^n, |x-x_0| < R_2$$
> >     then
> >     $$f(x)g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (x-x_0)^n, |x-x_0| < R$$
> >     Where
> >     $$c_n =  \sum_{r=0}^{n} a_rb_{n-r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n} a_{n-r}b_{r} \\ R \geq \min \{R_1, R_2\}$$
>
> Use the theorem above to find the first four nonzero terms in the Maclaurin of $$e^x \sin x$$

My understanding **RE-EDIT based on Answers**

$$f(x) \rightarrow 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 +\frac{1}{5!} x^5 ...
\\ g(x) \rightarrow 0+ x + 0 - \frac{1}{3!} x^3  +    0  + \frac{1}{5!} x^5 ...  $$

$$c_0 = \sum_{r=0}^{0} a_r b_{n-r} = a_0b_0 = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$
$$c_1 = \sum_{r=0}^{1} a_r b_{n-r} = a_0b_1 +a_1b_0  = 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 0 =1$$
$$c_2 = \sum_{r=0}^{2} a_r b_{n-r} = a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0 = 1$$
$$c_3 = ... = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$c_4 = ... = 0$$
$$c_5 = ... = - \frac{1}{30}$$

The first four nonzero terms of $e^x \sin x$:
$$ \implies c_1 x^1+ c_2 x^2  +c_3 x^3 + c_5 x^5 $$
$$ \implies  x+ x^2 +\frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{1}{30} x^5$$

Would this be correct?

Thx for your input

Comment: No, you are computing the coefficient of $x^7$, while the question is about the first four nonzero terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 + x + \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 +\cdots\\\times
\\ 0+ x + 0 - \frac{1}{3!} x^3  +    0  +  \frac{1}{5!} x^5+\cdots$$

Collect the products of coefficients leading to a common power and you get

$$x^0\to1\cdot0\\
x^1\to1\cdot0+1\cdot1\\
x^2\to\frac1{2!}0+1\cdot1+1\cdot0\\
x^3\to\frac1{3!}0+\frac1{2!}1+1\cdot0-1\frac1{3!}\\
x^4\to\frac1{4!}0+\frac1{3!}1+\frac1{2!}0-1\frac1{3!}+1\cdot0\\
x^5\to\frac1{5!}0+\frac1{4!}1+\frac1{3!}0-\frac1{2!}\frac1{3!}-1\cdot0+1\cdot\frac1{5!}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, just a way to check your work.

The given function is the imaginary part of $e^{(1+i)x}$. 
Then the requested coefficients are the imaginary parts of

$$\frac{(1+i)^k}{k!},$$ i.e.

$$0,1,1,\frac13,0,-\frac1{30},-\frac1{90},-\frac1{630}\cdots$$

Comment: Not an answer but a nice way !

Comment: I did a re-edit. I think I got it. Thx so much!